# Is EL&U experiencing diminishing returns of question quality?

Tags: discussion

I think it'd be interesting to statistically find this out. One could take samples from every year of EL&U and compare the amount of average upvoted and downvoted questions to get a more concrete comparison, but looking at even a few years ago questions were getting upvoted a lot more frequently

Comment: Do you think votes (in absolute or relative terms) are a good measure of quality? I think you'd have to at least take into account views as well because more views mean more (up) votes. In turn, more views don't necessarily mean a good quality question or answer.

Comment: Many low quality questions from years ago have been deleted, so even if we could measure quality reliably, we have no way of getting an accurate count.

Comment: Pure personal opinion, but most Single Word Request questions that got into Hot Network Questions then upvoted into <s>oblivion</s> skyline were not that good in quality...

Comment: There are surely back-end counts of views and user activity, but I can't imagine a straightforward way to translate that into *question quality*, which is a far more subjective measure.

Comment: Years ago, people were zealously drawing (an arbitrary) distinction between ELU and ELL, and basically sending all and sundry to ELL. Maybe they've just given up?

Comment: When is this site going to understand that some things cannot be quantified? The quality issue in language often involves intangibles that are basically not measurable, in my opinion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we reverse the trend on low quality questions?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/can-we-reverse-the-trend-on-low-quality-questions)

Comment: Eventually, a site like this becomes a wiki.  All the good questions have been asked and answered, so when they are re-asked, they are dismissed as duplicates. Only ELL students have anything new to ask.

Comment: @remarkl I don’t know if I share your confidence that we could get all of the questions about English completely answered more quickly than the language is changing. I’m sure there are already some older questions that could benefit from a more modern answer.

Comment: @ColleenV  You may be right, but the question would still be flagged as a duplicate!   Yes, the language is changing, but, IMHO, not rapidly enough to restock the lake with low-hanging fruit. I am fairly new to EL&U, taking time off from Seeking Alpha to mix a few metaphors and exercise a different part of my brain.  I was a lawyer and, as such, lived by precise and rule-bound language.  Transition is the enemy of precision, and, simply put, I'm ag'in' it.

Comment: If this is *actually* a duplicate of the seven-year-old question it's been suggested it is, that can only mean that the quality of questions has *continued* to diminish over the last seven years. (Or that it diminished, then increased, then diminished again, in at least one cycle.) It's much more likely that this is nothing more than the eternal trope of *things were better in the past*, something that is almost always stated, but seldom actually backed up by any real evidence.

Comment: Love "restocking the lake with low-hanging fruit"!  But to answer your question: "Yes".  Or maybe I am getting jaded.

Comment: What has certainly changed is the *rate of new questions*, which has significantly increased even just in the last six months, let alone in the last 6 years. Real data on this should be easy for our more code-literate members to extract. As awareness of our site grows, we're increasingly seen as the place to ask where the comma goes or when to use *which* vs *that*. It's not that these LQQs weren't being asked years ago; it's just that the greater volume of traffic means more such questions are being asked. The price of popularity/success...